# Regex unbalanced parenthesis error while finding phone numbers

Tags: python, regex

I am using Regex and got an error of unbalanced parenthesis while finding phone numbers at position 32. Image of error is given

```
import re

Regex_digit = re.compile(r'((\d\d\d-)? \d\d\d-\d\d\d\d(,))?) {3}')

Regex_digit.search('Hello, you can call me at 144-245-1452,152-632,414-156-3552')
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4DNZN.png)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please, post text information like code, logs and errors as text not images. It will help other site visitors in searching your question.

Comment: As for the question: you have an extra closing parenthesis in your regular expression (on the 32nd position as the error states).

Comment: You could try counting 32 characters into the regex, and see where the unbalanced paren is at... then balanace it or remove it.

Comment: but it would be more clear then i think

Comment: ok, let me try then

Comment: There is no `print` statement; why should it print anything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the supposed phone numbers in the string:

`'Hello, you can call me at 144-245-1452,152-632,414-156-3552'`

We expect the output to be able to capture all of the followings;

1. 144-245-1452
2. 414-156-3552

Given your regex, the pattern that would work would be;

`Regex_digit = re.compile(r'(\d\d\d-)?(\d\d\d)-(\d\d\d\d)')`

There are 3 capturing groups here.

`(\d\d\d-)?` -  optionally matches 3 digits [0-9].

`(\d\d\d)` -  matches 3 digits [0-9]. Exactly 3 times.

`-` - matches the character `-` literally.

`(\d\d\d\d)` - matches 4 digits [0-9].

```
result = Regex_digit.search('Hello, you can call me at 144-245-1452,152-632,414-156-3552')

print(result)
```

> <re.Match object; span=(26, 38), match='144-245-1452'>

However search would only give you the first matching pattern in the string.

To get all matching pattern;

```
string = 'Hello, you can call me at 144-245-1452,152-632,414-156-3552'
result = Regex_digit.findall(string)

print(result)
```

Because we have 3 capturing groups, you'd get a list of tuples. With each tuple containing 3 items from the capturing group.

To get back the result as a list of strings, you can use the join method;

```
print(["".join(x) for x in re.findall(Regex_digit, s)])
```

Refactored pattern would be;

```
regex_digit = re.compile(r'(\d{3}-)?(\d{3})-(\d{4})')
```

It means same thing as discussed above.

Answer (score 0):

in your case thus error occurres because you have more closing parenthesis than opening parenthesis, to be balanced it will be like this:

```
r'((\d\d\d-)? \d\d\d-\d\d\d\d(,)?){3}'
```